# Extremely strange Windows 7 wireless issue: Existing connections stay open, but can't open new ones

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have been having this issue forever now. I have no idea why or what is causing it and am completely stuck.

I use a USB Wifi adapter for my computer and it normally connects fine. However, after some usage (key word: usage. If I leave the computer locked, the issue will never happen, no matter how long) it will fail to open new connections. As in, if I try to open a new tab in Chrome, it times out. If I try to ping a server, timeout. However, any existing connections stay open. Skype continues to work. IRC stays connected. Youtube videos keep downloading. The only issue is with a new connection or closing/reopening one. The absolute only fix is to disconnect and reconnect the adapter.

I have even purchased a new wireless adapter and it has the exact same problem.

I'm running Windows 7.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you ping something on your local network?

Comment: First, I second Paul's question -- does local connectivity fail as well as Internet connectivity? Second, are you sure the limitation isn't coming from the router hitting its NAT limit? Do other computers not experience this problem? What make/model router do you have? Are you using any clustering downloaders (like torrent downloaders)?

Comment: Yep, exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: I'll test these things the next time it happens. Thank you.

Comment: So, turns out: I *can* still ping internal IP addresses and the router itself. But pinging an outside domain name (or an outside IP address) times out.